# javascript: smallest JSON.stringify for Float32Array?

Tags: javascript, stringify

FireFox 46.0.1:  I am using 3rd-party (easyrtc) software to send 15KB chunks of Float32Arrays between peers.  Easyrtc insists that the data be JSON-able.  Unfortunately, JSON.stringify yields a string more than twice as long as the original data:  16384 bytes of data becomes a string of length 35755.  Below is my test code followed by the console output.  What if anything can I do to reduce the stringify'd size?  Is there a way to send the values only (no keys)?  Can I use the 'replacer' argument to send only the values, and if so, don't I need to use a replacer on the corresponding JSON.parse on the receiving end?

```
var g_testBufferNBytes = 4096 * 4;
var g_testBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(g_testBufferNBytes);
var g_testBufferView   = new Float32Array(g_testBuffer);
console.log("array byte length " + g_testBuffer.byteLength); 
console.log("view byte length " + g_testBufferView.byteLength);
var j = JSON.stringify(g_testBufferView);
console.log("j length " + j.length);
var newBuf = JSON.parse(j);
console.log("newBuf length " + Object.keys(newBuf).length);
```

CONSOLE:
array byte length 16384
view byte length 16384
j length 35755
newBuf length 4096

Comment: What is it you are trying to do exactly? The library you are using seems to have a method to send binary data directly. https://demo.easyrtc.com/demos/demo_data_channel_filesharing.html

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

**ES6**: Assume that your data are in `let f32 = g_testBufferView`  (array `Float32Array`) ) - whe can save it as JSON array in at leas 4 ways:

```
// code 
let f32json = JSON.stringify(f32);
let f32jsonArr = JSON.stringify(Array.from(f32));
let f32base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...(new Uint8Array(f32.buffer))));
let f32base128 = ... // not trivial, look below


// decode
let df32json = new Float32Array(Object.values(JSON.parse(f32json))); 
let df32jsonArr = new Float32Array(JSON.parse(f32jsonArr));
let df32base64 = new Float32Array(new Uint8Array([...atob(f32base64)].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))).buffer);
let df32base128 = ... // not trivial, look below
```

Note that `Object.values` return values sorted by numeric keys (look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Examples)).

Here is [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/nvt08hye/8/). You can also use **base128** do decode but I not use in this example (to not complicate it) - more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53117800/860099).

If your `Float32Array`- `f32` has 4096 elements equals to `0.3` then:

- `f32` has 16384 bytes,
- `f32json` (`j` from your question) has 109483 bytes (which is >6x bigger than `f32`)
- `f32jsonArr`  has 81921 bytes (which is >5x bigger than `f32`)
- `f32base64`  has 21848 bytes(which is ~1.3x bigger than `f32`)
- `f32base128` has 18725 bytes (whis is <1.15x bigger than `f32`) but chrome will send ~2x bigger request (depends on input data)

If your `Float32Array`- `f32` has 4096 elements equals integer  from 1 to 9 then:

- `f32` has 16384 bytes - **CONST**,
- `f32json` (`j` from your question) has 35755 bytes (which is >2x bigger than `f32`)
- `f32jsonArr`  has 8193 bytes (which is 2x **SMALLER** (sic!) than `f32`)
- `f32base64`  has 21848 bytes - **CONST** (which is ~1.3x bigger than `f32`)
- `f32base128` has 18725 bytes - **CONST** (whis is <1.15x bigger than `f32`) but chrome will send ~2x bigger request (depends on input data)

### Conclusion

The smallest result which not depends of array values (result size is constant) we get for `f32base64`  ~33% bigger than input array size. For `f32base128`  - it contains valid JSON (string) which is something about <15% bigger than input, but chrome during sending increase this size ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53117801/860099) - on 'update' section). So use `f32base64` - this is probably the smallest JSON that you can get without more sophisticated methods.