# Convert array of bytes to base128 valid JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I want to send big array of bytes using JSON (I was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330746/javascript-smallest-json-stringify-for-float32array/53108630#53108630)), to have small overhead I wana to use base128 encoding (which can in fact produce valid json string). But unfortunately I was unable to find some procedures which do that conversions in JS. I will publish my procedures as answer to this question, however may be someone has shorter procedures or may be better idea to effective sending binary data inside JSON.

Comment: Isn't gzip compression supposed to [do this](https://gist.github.com/jordansissel/3044155) for you?

Comment: @bigless the word "compression" was in duble-quotes - the question is about effectively send binary data (maybe compressed) inside JSON (you can ofcourse compress that data using zip before sending them as json).

Comment: Is this a case of converting base 2 number to base 128 ?

Comment: @Trunk byte = 8bit = 256 values

Comment: I see. 7 bit encoding. Looks like you answered your own question !

Comment: I know OP might not be interested in this question, but for any real-case, please, consider why you need to send binary data as JSON. There are means to send binary data as binary data, and this will always be the best and should be preferred way of doing.

Comment: @Kaiido - sorry I send wrong link in prev comment (I delete it), here is probably real life example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37330746/860099

Comment: Well even there they probably just don't need it. I don't know the library they are using, but it seems to have a proper method to send binary data directly: https://demo.easyrtc.com/demos/demo_data_channel_filesharing.html And webRTC's [send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/send) does accept binary data directly, so really no need to convert it to a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ES6:

Encode

```
let bytesToBase128 = (bytesArr) => {
    // 128 characters to encode as json-string
    let c= "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz¼½ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ" 
    let fbits=[]; 
    let bits = (n,b=8) => [...Array(b)].map((x,i)=>n>>i&1); 
    bytesArr.map(x=> fbits.push(...bits(x)));

    let fout=[]; 
    for(let i =0; i<fbits.length/7; i++) { 
        fout.push(parseInt(fbits.slice(i*7, i*7+7).reverse().join(''),2))  
    }; 

    return (fout.map(x => c[x])).join('');
}

// Example
// bytesToBase128([23, 45, 65, 129, 254, 42, 1, 255]) => "NÚ4AèßÊ0ÿ1"
```

Decode

```
let base128ToBytes = (base128str) => {
    // 128 characters to encode as json-string
    let c= "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz¼½ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ" 

    dfout = base128str.split('').map(x=>c.indexOf(x));
    let dfbits = [];
    let bits = (n,b=8) => [...Array(b)].map((x,i)=>n>>i&1);
    dfout.map(x=> dfbits.push(...bits(x,7) ));

    let dfbytes=[]; 
    let m1 = dfbits.length%8 ? 1 : 0;
    for(let i =0; i<dfbits.length/8-m1; i++) { 
        dfbytes.push(parseInt(dfbits.slice(i*8, i*8+8).reverse().join(''),2))  
    }; 

    return dfbytes;
}

// Example
// base128ToBytes("NÚ4AèßÊ0ÿ1") => [23, 45, 65, 129, 254, 42, 1, 255]
```

I embeded here `bits` function - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53115892/860099). The coversion idea here is to convert bytes array to bit array and then take each 7 bits (the value is from 0 to 127) as character number  i charakter list `c`. In decoding we change each character number 7-bit number and create array, and then take each 8-bit packages of this array and interpret them as byte.

To view characters from ASCI and choose 128 from them (which is arbitrary) I type in console

```
[...Array(256)].map((x,i) => String.fromCharCode(i)).join('');
```

I try to avoid characters that has "special meaning" in different contexts like  `! @ # $ % ' & ...`

And here is [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/7153c9x0/10/) (which convert `Float32Array` to json).

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Safari

### Conclusion

After conversion bytes array to base128 string (which is valid json) the output string is less than `15%` bigger than input array.

## Update

A dig a little bit more, and expose that when we send characters which codes are bigger than 128 (`¼½ÀÁÂÃÄ...`) then chrome in fact send TWO characters (bytes) instead one :( - I made test in this way: type in url bar **chrome://net-internals/#events** (and send POST request) and in *URL_REQUEST> HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST > UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT > total_size* we see that request are two times bigger when body contains charaters witch codes bigger than 128. So in fact we don't have profit with sending this characters :( . For base64 strings we not observe such negative behaviour - However I left this procedures because they may bye used in other purposes than sending (like better alternative to storage binary data in localstorage than base64 - however probably there exists even better ways...?). **UPDATE 2019** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135233/860099).